# 2D Tiled Game Optimization in Java

Tags: java, 2d, storage, tile

I'm working on a 2d top down game in pure Java and until now I've got a noise mapping system that works with chunks of tiles (and entities) just like Minecraft.

The way I store tiles is by creating a `int[s * s]` array, where `s` is the size (in tiles) that a side of the chunk has. Then, I have a static array of Tiles which contains each of the possible tiles in the game, indexed with an integer. Those are the integers stored in the `int[s * s]` in each chunk. Now, I want to be able to overlay tiles, such as invisible spawn tiles, walls, trees and transition tiles (like when grass changes to sand: there should be a border of grass over the sand, which would be a new tile).

The problem is that only one integer can be stored in each coordinate of the chunk. Another way to do it would be to put actual instances of the tiles inside the chunks and make the overlaying tiles point to the ones directly below them (like a stack), but I think that's kind of a bad approach. Another approach which I tested was to make an array of Lists of tiles, that was also really bad.

Which would be a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would separate the storage for tiles and objects.

- You would have an `int [w*h]` or similar for the tiles themselves,
  which would only allow one tile per square.
- Separately, you could have a `ArrayList [w*h]` which stores a list of
  entities in each square. This array would contain `null` for empty
  squares, so the extra storage cost for the majority of squares (that
  have no entities in them) is minimal.

There are other approaches of course, but this has the advantage that it is both simple and pretty efficient.

Only real downside is that you will have to write separate code for handling tiles and entities - but since you usually handle tiles and entities differently anyway then this is unlikely to be a big problem.

Comment: All right, so by doing this I would have to turn my trees, spawners etc into entities, which would be no problem, actually. That's nice. But what if I want to "blend" tiles? An example is the transition from grass to sand: I would need kind of a border of grass inside the sand tile. What I wanted to do was to make this border a new Tile and just draw it over the sand, which would require 2 tiles in the same place (or not?).

Comment: several ways you can implement borders: a) just detect them and draw them while rendering b) have them as entities c) implement tile overlays (multiple tiles per square, like entities) d) auto-generate multiple versions of tiles with borders. I'd probably prefer a) usually, but YMMV and it depends a bit on your overall engine design and the amount of artistic flexibility you want to have.